# Fetching google plus news feed like facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, google-api, google-plus

I am facing 2 issues regarding the `google plus` implementation.

1. I am trying to fetch google plus feeds like Facebook.  I found
   number of posts for the same question, but none of those give me
   proper answer. 
   From google developer site, I found API to fetch activities.
   But it is providing selected users posts, not the wall posts.
2. For sharing text/photo on `google plus`, google is proving native share dialog
   box. How can I post without using default share box?

Provide me some solution for these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. There is a [feature request for point one](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=25) and a [feature request for point two](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this code.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
div {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
body {margin: 25px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
</style>
</body>
<div id="" style="overflow: auto; height:400px; width:495px;">
<h1>Change this title</h1>
<h5><i>Write your description here (or completely omit it)...</i></h5>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" async defer></script>
<div  class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+google/posts/PXaD8t9AKpi"></div>
<div  class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+google/posts/QDj9aCTypaT"></div>
<div  class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+google/posts/Cb2TMZ5nbK8"></div>
<div  class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+google/posts/KjRqbTq3p6L"></div>
<div  class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+google/posts/67dnaBW6fnp"></div>
<div  class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+google/posts/iq65sndanF4"></div>
<p><b>Read this: </b>Replace the data-href tag content with the link of your post(s). Duplicate, delete, and create posts at will. You can remove this text and the button that follows it. If you are viewing this as code, you should remember that you do not need to give credits. You should acknowledge that you have to manually update posts, and you can sort through your posts and display the ones you want.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Yup, that's it.